# Avid Media Composer Not Importing MP4s

Tags: mp4, avid

I just installed Avid Media Composer 8.4.1, and am trying to edit some screen captured MP4s H.264 format I recorded with OBS.

However, when I try to import,transcode or link to file the video layer isn't there and I only get the audio. Also I have no AMA option.

I've made several projects thinking maybe the file configurations were different then the project's but that hasn't helped. Am I missing a plugin or something, because I can import these same files into Adobe Premiere Pro just fine?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

If it helps my specs are:
AMD FX-8350 4.2GHz 8-core CPU
Gigabyte GeForce GTX 960 4GB GPU
16 GB of G.Skill Ripjaws 1600 DDR3 Memory
and 2 Western Digital Black 1TB 64MB Internal HDD

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to work with MP4s generated by OBS and Vegas Pro wouldn't display the video. Had to change import plugin used by Vegas. So, in your case, I'd suggest re-encoding to MP4 using Handbrake or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I just don't get why, when OBS uses the same H.264 encode as everyone else, so many NLEs have such a problem with it's MP4 files.

Comment: Sounds to me like your h264 compression is not digestible by the Media Composer you've installed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your video files are encoded using variable frame rate, which is typical of screen recorders. Premiere is trying to kind of grunt through it, but on longer clips you'll probably notice that you get some synch drift with the audio.

Transcoding for a constant frame rate file, either going back to H.264 (where you might lose some quality) or to something more editing-friendly, like DNxHD. ffmpeg can handle this pretty easily. Just be aware of the limited number of [video formats that DNxHD supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Avid_DNxHD_resolutions).

Answer (score 0):

mp4/h264 files are super compressed files and require a lot of horse-power to read. that's why a lot of machines and programs have trouble with them. also, they suck if you are trying to do precise synch-based work. work with proper codecs, ProRes or DNxHD.